# Powershell - parse from CSV Second Column "Owners" and keep output of failures

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get a list of AD Group owners from a CSV file, the second column is what I want to pull from, it is titled Owners I want to keep the output if there are failures as well. Would I just modify the "foreach" portion of my code?

```
Get-Content "C:\tmp\SMB.csv" -OutVariable  | foreach {
Get-ADGroup -identity $_ -properties name,managedby| select name,managedby | 
    out-file c:\temp\test.csv -Append }
```

Comment: Well first, do you need to save the content into a variable? If so, I believe you need to specify a name for said variable. (e.g. '-OutVariable Output'). Second, the '$_' automatic variable in the for loop, it's probably not in the right format for specifying the identity? As written I'm thinking it's a full line of the csv file for each iteration... which won't work. Are you getting an error? Try printing the $_ to figure out exactly what you are trying to send to the -identity parameter of Get-ADGroup, and go from there...

Answer (score 0):

To get the owners values just use

```
Get-Content 'C:\tmp\SMB.csv' | ConvertFrom-Csv | Select Owners
```